# How to provide statistical evidence that an experimental method is providing higher mean percentages?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, t-test, p-value, computational-statistics

I performed an experiment using two different methods. The data are percentages and higher percentages indicate a better method. The results were as follows:

```
Method 1 :74.47,79.34,72.85,83.54,75.18,73.58,70.06,
          73.35,74.41,78.35,73.14,81.55,76.21,74.67

Method 2: 83.25,85.14,81.61,77.59,79.38,80.24,79.94,82.54,78.22,
          83.21,82.54,77.67,83.51,78.87
```

The mean of method 1 is 76.75 and that from method 2 is 80.97

I claimed that method 2 is better because of the value of the mean.
I have been asked by reviewers to provide strongs statical evidence that method 2 performs better than method 1.

Specifically:

> Comment 1: Results would become reliable within a statistical
>   framework offering p-values or other statistical measures of
>   difference.
>
> Comment 2: A statistical analysis should be carried on in order to
>   provide strong evidence with regard to the best performance of Method
>   2 over Method 1.

Comment: In fact, these values are in percentage and higher percentage means a better result

Comment: And also, the two methods were applied on same subjects i.e. we applied method one on 14 subjects and got the results and then applied method two on same 14 subjects and got the results

Comment: the information on the pairing is very important. (Are the observations in the same order?)  You probably want a paired t-test or signed rank test or sign test or a permutation test or ...

Comment: @ Glen_b : Yes the observations are in the same order

Comment: I also need to know that how would we calculate and what would be the t and p-values ? are my results really statistically significant ?

Comment: You probably want a paired t-test (p=0.001323) or signed rank test (p=0.004028) or sign test (p=0.01294) or a permutation test or a bootstrap test or ... Any of these are easily done in R, or even something like Excel. Or by hand, e.g. [here](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/parametric_methods/ptt.htm) - or google *paired t test* and find it in a bunch of places.

Comment: I can give details if you really need them, or I could paste results in from R if those are your full data.

Comment: I really need the details

Answer (score 1):

[A good place to find more on this stuff would be in many introductory college-level texts.]

My biggest concern would be that with percentages, the variance is unlikely to be constant. This would be an issue because the t-test (for example) would be based on assuming that the differences are observations from a population with a common mean and common variance, when in fact the differences for the larger observations are likely to become "squeezed up"; the closer they get to 100%, if they can't go over it. That is, the variance of the differences will depend on the sizes of the observations in the difference. The distribution of the test statistic will be impacted - to be specific, the nominal significance level will not reflect the actual rejection rate under the null hypothesis. The power, too, will be affected.

--

For the t-test:

Let x = score on method 1, y = score on method 2

To test the null hypothesis that the true mean difference is zero:

1. Calculate the difference ($d_i = y_i − x_i$) between the two observations on each pair, keeping the sign.
2. Calculate the mean of the differences, $\bar{d}$.
3. Calculate the standard deviation of the differences, $s_d$, and use this to calculate the standard error of the mean difference, $s_{\bar{d}} = \frac{s_d}{\sqrt{n}}$
4. Calculate the t-statistic, which is given by $T = \frac{\bar{d}}{s_{\bar{d}}}$ . 
   Under the null hypothesis,
   this statistic follows a $t$-distribution with $n−1$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the number of pairs.
5. Use tables of the $t$-distribution to compare your value for $T$ to the $t_{n−1}$ distribution. This will give the $p$-value for the paired $t$-test.

Uh, is this homework? What was the experiment about?

***Edit:*** example calculations:

In **R**:

```
Method1 <-c(74.47,79.34,72.85,83.54,75.18,73.58,70.06,
           73.35,74.41,78.35,73.14,81.55,76.21,74.67)

Method2 <- c(83.25,85.14,81.61,77.59,79.38,80.24,79.94,82.54,78.22,
           83.21,82.54,77.67,83.51,78.87)


> t.test(Method1,Method2,paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  Method1 and Method2 
t = -4.071, df = 13, p-value = 0.001323
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -7.982491 -2.447509 
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                 -5.215
```

OR:

```
> wilcox.test(Method1,Method2,paired=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  Method1 and Method2 
V = 9, p-value = 0.004028
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

OR (sign test):

```
> binom.test(sum(Method1>Method2),length(Method1))

    Exact binomial test

data:  sum(Method1 > Method2) and length(Method1) 
number of successes = 2, number of trials = 14, p-value = 0.01294
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01779452 0.42812916 
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.1428571
```

OR (permutation test):

```
diffs <- Method1 - Method2
f3 <- 2*outer(0:(2^14-1),2^(0:13),function(x,y) (x %/% y) %% 2) -1
res <- rowMeans(f3*matrix(rep(diffs,each=2^14),nc=14))
data.frame(pvalue = sum(abs(res)>=abs(mean(diffs)))/2^14,row.names=" ")
       pvalue
  0.003417969
```

etc . . .

Comment: No its not a home work , its part of a research , what happens if the variance is not constant? I mean why are you concerned about it ?

Comment: It's an assumption of the test. At least the percentages cover a fairly narrow range, so it shouldn't be terribly drastic in impact

Comment: @ Glen_b: I am really very thankful to you for your help. The experiment was about acquiring human brain signals using two different methods of same 14 subjects and show that one method performs significantly better than the other.

Comment: I've included some standard analyses that might be used.

Comment: @conarch I've added an edit to better explain the variance issue

Comment: -1 to the question, since it has become clear that what was sought was for someone to do the work rather than to teach the method(s).  +1 to the answer, though we don't want to "rub it in" that someone's question is a basic one.  Those are welcome here, just as the more advanced ones, are, right?

Comment: @rolando2 I can see how one might take it as ungenerous, though that wasn't really the intent. I will try to modify the apparent tone. Certainly reasonably basic questions are welcome

Comment: Sounds good, @Glen_b.