# two sample mean comparison with small and nonnormal data

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have three groups. Both have small sample sizes (<10). And we can't check the assumption of normality. I want to compare any two of them.

What to do in this case( unequal small sizes, non-normality)

Comment: How about a permutation test? You may not have much here with such small samples, but on the plus side you can do full enumeration.

Comment: I don't understand. How to carry out a permutation test ？ What's its assumptions?

Comment: So much I want to say about this, but first some questions -- when you say 'I want to compare them' - what is it you're trying to compare? Do you mean to compare locations? Is there a specific alternative? Are you talking about 3 pairwise comparisons or are you after something notionally more like a one-way ANOVA? (The suitability of permutation tests will be affected by how small the sample sizes are -- if they're small enough, you won't be able to get below some specific significance levels; on the other hand, outside specific parametric assumptions you may not have much choice about that)

Comment: A good description of a permutation test will not fit in a comment. But check Wikipedia under "Resampling" for a decent start.

Comment: Actually I did anova and rejected the null hypothesis. So I want to know the pair comparison results.

Comment: So does that mean you want to change your question to 'how do I do multiple comparisons after an ANOVA?' or do you actually want to know something like 'how do I do something like an ANOVA and multiple comparisons but without assuming normality?' ...? (Incidentally, what are your sample sizes?)

Answer (score 2):

(This is too long for a comment; if the question is sufficiently clarified - see the comments - it may be edited into a better answer.)

On permutation tests:

The basic idea of a permutation test is that if the null hypothesis is true, the group/category labels are arbitrary and could be reassigned without changing the distribution of the groups. So they *are* reassigned, in every fashion and a test statistic sensitive to the alternative is calculated; if the null is true, the sample should be a randomly chosen member of that permutation distribution. If the alternative is true, the sample should tend toward being 'extreme' in that distribution (extreme in a sense defined by the ordering resulting from what is most consistent with the alternative).

There's some discussion of permutation tests [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74918/shuffle-my-data-to-investigate-differences-between-3-groups/74919#74919), discussion of why they might be used [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63863/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-permutation-tests/63868#63868), discussion of the relationship between permutation tests and randomization tests [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55742/difference-between-randomization-test-and-permutation-test/55780#55780), and a little on the choice between permutation tests and t-tests [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56194/is-it-possible-to-use-a-two-sample-t-test-here/56216#56216).

There are examples of different permutation tests done [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64212/randomisation-permutation-test-for-paired-vectors-in-r/64215#64215)  and 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74507/compare-dispersion-between-two-distributions-with-thick-tails/74591#74591) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53053/mann-whitney-or-two-tailed-t-test/53054#53054) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/how-to-provide-statistical-evidence-that-an-experimental-method-is-providing-hig/43281#43281) (see near the end).

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you use your power to detect differences will be low. Another possible approach would be using non-parametric tests. If you have three groups you could use Kruskal-Wallis (followed by a multiple comparison procedure if you want to compare them pairwise).

In R you can use `kruskal.test` for the Kruskall Wallis test and `kruskalmc` in the *pgirmess* package for multiple comparisons

Comment: `No matter what you use your power to detect differences will be low` How to understand this?

Comment: OMG: With sample size so small, the power will be low.